# Why does the query with multiple == where conditions not return data?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, multiple-conditions

I have the following code:

```
const gpTransactions = await col
.where("creditCard", "==", "Revolut")
.get()
.then((qry) =>
  qry.docs.map((doc) => {
    const {
      currency: ccy,
      amount: amt,
      creditCard: cc,
      id: gpid,
      timestamp: tsp,
      app,
    } = doc.data();
    return { ccy, amt, gpid, tsp, cc, app };
  })
)
.catch((e) => console.log("Retrieving Google Pay Transactions failed", e));
```

It returns the following:

```
  {
    ccy: 'USD',
    amt: 34,
    gpid: 'y0Xrbd2xVT0GVArBk4II',
    tsp: 1618326201867,
    cc: 'Revolut',
    app: 'Google Pay'
  },
  {
    ccy: 'EUR',
    amt: 50.22,
    gpid: 'yyRj3Rx7iHMozNw0eeNn',
    tsp: 1607613999306,
    cc: 'Revolut',
    app: 'Google Pay'
  }
```

If I now run the query again but add a further `.where()`, I retrieve an empty set:

```
const gpTransactions = await col
    .where("creditCard", "==", "Revolut")
    .where("app", "==", "Google Pay")
    .get()
    .then((qry) => ...
```

I don't have a `composite index`, but if I check the docs, I don't think it is require given that I want to combine two `==` (logical `AND`).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: Your data and query don't match (`cc` vs `creditCard`). I'm going to assume that's a typo in the question, but you might want to double check and update the question with the correct field name in both places.

Comment: Without that typo, it works for me though: https://jsbin.com/liceyeh/edit?js,console. I did not create any manual/composite indexes, so I'm not sure what the difference is. If the problem persists for you after fixing the mismatched field name, can you set up a reproduction in a similar site?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are doing god's work by being nonstop available. `cc` in the data is due to object destructuring `...creditCard: cc,...`. It does not seem to work for me weirdly.

Comment: Ok, this is very, very weird. I typed `Google Pay` manually and then it didn't work. Now, I went with `Google Pay` which I copied from the database and there it is different. Is this a known thing?

Comment: @Spurious could you explain what the issue is apart from destructuring ??

Comment: The issue seems to be a weird character thing to be honest. It works now, because I copy & pasted the entry instead of typing it.

Comment: It indeed sounds like you may have some invisible characters in there. I'd check on a site to see what they are: https://www.google.com/search?q=show+unicode+characters

Answer (score 0):

As pointed, the field name should be the same in your query.

```
const gpTransactions = await col
    .where("cc", "==", "Revolut")
    .where("app", "==", "Google Pay")
    .get()
    .then((qry) => ...
```

Comment: It is `creditCard` in firestore, I use object destructuring and rename `creditCard` to `cc`.